# Using an Xbee on raspberry pi 3 model b

Tags: pi-3, wireless, sensor, xbee

I'm a complete newbie to using Raspberry Pi (pi 3 model b). I want to build a smart CO and smoke alarm from scratch, I know what sensors I want to use ( Mq 2 for smoke and mq-7 for CO), however I want the sensors to transmit data wirelessly to the Raspberry Pi. Is this possible with using an Xbee on each sensor? I also want to transmit data from the Raspberry Pi to a wireless network, again would a Xbee be suitable for this?

Answer (score 0):

any wireless standart should work, provided You use correct transmitter and libraries. But such sensors have quite high consumption, You should consider using mems types, or are You planning to have wired power supply?

Comment: what MEMS sensors would be useful for this?